# Why don't repeated calls to glDrawArrays appear to be drawing in a GLKView on iOS?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, glkview

I am attempting to redraw with the same arrays using glDrawArrays in a GLKView on iOS. When I comment out any two of these calls, the other draw call draws as I expect. My last hunch was that I was attempting to draw at the same depth, so I introduced a depth uniform and am setting the depth in the vertex shader like so:

```
gl_Position = vec4(position.xy, 0.1*depth, 1.0);
```

the depth coming in is a lowp vector with a value of 0, 1, or 2. This didn't have any effect.

Here is my drawRect: method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClearColor(0., 0.0, 0.0, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Render the object again with ES2
    glUseProgram(_program);


    // the colors
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _wheelMaskTexture);
    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE], 0);

    glUniform1f(uniforms[UNIFORM_COLOR_DEPTH], COLOR_DRAW);
    glUniform1f(uniforms[UNIFORM_COLOR_ANGLE], _angle);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);


    // the sat
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _satMaskTexture);
    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE], 0);

    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_COLOR_DEPTH], SATURATION_DRAW);
    glUniform1f(uniforms[UNIFORM_COLOR_ANGLE], _satAngle);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);


    // the bright
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _brightMaskTexture);
    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_TEXTURE], 0);

    glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_COLOR_DEPTH], BRIGHTNESS_DRAW);
    glUniform1f(uniforms[UNIFORM_COLOR_ANGLE], _brightnessAngle);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```

My GLKView is set up with a `drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24`. I haven't set up any transforms because what I'm drawing is basically a simple color wheel.

There is no world or model transform. I'm simply drawing the same square 3 times one on top of the other without transforming. There are 3 different mask images that are used to mask out the fragments that I care about in the fragment shader like so:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, texture2D(wheelMask, texCoord).a);
```

Why wouldn't all three `glDrawArrays` calls draw as expected? As I mentioned early any one of them by themselves draws as expected. As it is, with all three, only the first `glDrawArrays` draws as expected.

Comment: That is weird. Could you simply try to disable the depth test.

Comment: Thanks, @MaticOblak I tried disabling the depth test (changed `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` to `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` with no luck. It's still drawing whichever item is a the lowest depth (smallest v coord).